# "How do I match typescript versions in my project as it shows error "requires typescript@>=2.7.0 <2.8.0"

Tags: angular

I have a problem with typescript version between my angular/CLI and my project. When I run

 `ng v`
I see the version of typescript is **2.7.2** but when I run my project with `ng serve`, I get this warning message saying:
**"@angular/compiler-cli@6.1.10 requires typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0' but 2.9.2 was found instead."**
There are solutions I tried.

1. I went to `package-lock.json` and I deleted it then I opened
   `package.json` and I changed the version `"typescript":"^2.8.0"` in **devDependencies** section. Then I ran `npm install` but
   this solution did not work and I got this error **"Failed to compile"**
2. I ran this command `npm install typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0'` but again I get the same error, **"Failed to compile"** after running `ng serve`.
3. I deleted `node_modules` folder and I deleted `packages-lock.json` and I changed typescript version in `package.json` to `~2.8.0` in **devDependencies section.** but again I get the same error, **"Failed to compile"**.
4. I tried to delete typescript 2.9.2 with this command `npm uninstall -g --save typescript@2.9.2` then I deleted `package-lock.json` and I changed typescript version in `package.json` to `~2.8.0` and after that, I ran `npm install`. Still, I got some warning message about typescript version.

I use Angular/CLI 6.0.8 and I want to know if I upgrade this version, would I be able to follow the course I am learning from, with newer version of CLI?


I have no idea how does angular work and check the version of typescript installed in the system and the one installed in the project. I want to understand this thing. I hope someone will clarify this and guide me for another solution.

Comment: If it is windows try with double quotes `npm install typescript@">=2.7.0 <2.8.0"` within your project folder

Comment: I did that already.

Comment: I knie this is an older question. You cannot use 2.8.0, because it says lower than `<`, not lower than or equals `<=`. Use `~2.7.0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @nayakam explained in comment. You need to use npm command inside project folder: `npm install typescript@">=2.7.0 <2.8.0"`

You can update each part of your libraries you can use different versions of them. Error you get is that, some library might not work with typescript version you have installed.

Comment: No, this does not always solve this problem. I did it with double quotes.

Comment: So if it not installed package find version between 2.7.0 and not higher then 2.8.0 and install it. Or avoid this message if app is working correct.

Comment: There is something not clear for me. The command `ng v` shows typescript 2.7.2. I use angular/cli 6.0.8. So is it possible to update only typescript without updating angular/cli?

Comment: Yes you can update each part of your libraries you can use different versions of them. Error you get is that some library might not work with typescript version you have installed.