# Am I going to face problems If I keep working on my Angular project while it shows warning message (requires typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0')?

Tags: angular

I am not able to solve the problem that is caused by the wrong version of typescript. When I run `ng serve`, I see this warning message:
**@angular/compiler-cli@6.1.10 requires typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0' but 2.8.4 was found instead.** 
I tried many solutions and I failed to solve it. I want to continue working on my project until I find a solution. Would it be difficult to solve it later on? Would it cause other problems in my project?

Comment: Just install the correct version of typescript. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/install-a-previous-version-of-a-package) or just edit your `package.json`.

Comment: Or better, avoid staying on an old version of Angular (and TypeScript), and upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I tried many solutions but I could not solve it. I tried many typescript versions but either it fails to compile or it compiles with that warning message.

Comment: @JBNizet , I am watching online course and I don't know If I can follow the instructor with a higher version. He uses angular/cli@6.0.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own post 2 hours prior... ["How do I match typescript versions in my project as it shows error "requires typescript@>=2.7.0 <2.8.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58470703/how-do-i-match-typescript-versions-in-my-project-as-it-shows-error-requires-ty)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a version range for packages to install in order to satisfy the requirements of the warning message:

```sh
npm i typescript@">=2.7.0 <2.8.0"
```

However, one caveat to note that version ranges should be placed in quotes if there are spaces:

> Note that most version ranges must be put in quotes so that your shell will treat it as a single argument. [*- `npm install` documentation*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

For more info about the `install` command, check out the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

---

Alternatively, to avoid these kind of dependency issues, consider updating your app to use the latest version of Angular. See the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io) for more info on how to upgrade and the [Keep your Angular Projects Up-to-Date](https://angular.io/guide/updating) guide on more info about upgrading.